# How to store Boolean type data into a column in a PostgreSQL db table with data type "bit" using HIbernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a variable of type Boolean in my entity class by name "isActive". It to mapped to a column by name "is_active" with data type as bit.

```
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean isActive;
```

But when ever I try to save isActive attribute of the object, I get an error:

```
column "is_active" is of type bit but expression is of type character 
varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How do I store the values the values of isActive? I want to store "1" in the database when value of "isActive" is true and "0" when "isActive" is false.

Thank you!

Comment: What don't you use a column with the `boolean` type? A `bit` is something different then a `boolean` You are not using an `integer` in Java either

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I have to use "1" for true values and "0" for false values. It's the code specification given to me.

Comment: Your question was "How to store boolean type into a column". The answer is "Use a column defined as `boolean`"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hibernate's NumericBooleanType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided) like so:

```
@Type(type = "numeric_boolean")
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean isActive;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below annotation above the field name, if using hibernate

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean isActive;
```